# ListLinePlot works for data similar up to 9 decimal numbers but does not work when similarity is up to 11 decimal numbers. Why?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy, rescale

Through the following code, Tcvalues are generated:

```
bein = 1/100;
befi = 100;
best = 1/1000;
parbe1 = {T1 -> 7, P -> 1, q -> 1/5};
parbe2 = {P -> 5/10, q -> 1/5}; 

xlog = Log10@Range[bein, befi, best];

tempPq5 = (6 + 16 P \[Pi] r^2 + 
     8 r^2 be^2 (1 - Sqrt[1 + q^2/(r^6 be^2)] + 
        Log[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 + q^2/(r^6 be^2)])]))/(12 \[Pi] r);

ParallelEvaluate[Off[FindRoot::lstol ]];

Launching <<4 local kernels>> 4/4

Tcvalues = ParallelTable[
   so[be] = 
    r /. FindRoot[(tempPq5 - T1 == 0) /. parbe1, {r, 5}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 20];
   (tempPq5 /. parbe2 /. r -> so[be])
   , {be, N[Range[bein, befi, best], 20]}];

minmax = MinMax[Tcvalues]
```

where minmax=${3.515223559132505129, 3.515223559797548663}$. 
It is seen that Tcvalues are similar up to 9 decimal numbers. We can plot it by

```
paired = Transpose@{xlog, Tcvalues};

ticks[min_, max_] := {#, NumberForm[#, {20, 10}]} & /@ 
  N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 8]]
ListLinePlot[paired, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Rescale[#, minmax, {0, 1}] &, 
   Rescale[#, {0, 1}, minmax] &}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, minmax}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.015], Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.8, ImageSize -> 400, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 13, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(10\)]\) (be)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(C\)]\)"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

[image]

But for another set of data:

```
parbe1 = {T1 -> 50, P -> 5, q -> 1/10};
parbe2 = {P -> 3, q -> 1/10};
```

for which minmax=${30.008491860258528396, 30.008491860259159538}$, similar up to 11 decimal points, the output is:

[image]

Could you please let me know how can I fix it?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this just reflects the precision of the numbers used internally in the plotting routine. Try multiplying everything by 100000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problems all come from insufficient working precision: somewhere, deep within the innards of `ListPlot`, some function is erroneously not using enough precision to differentiate your VERY similar values.

Instead of using `ScalingFunctions`, I propose to do the rescaling manually *before* feeding the data to `ListPlot`. I concentrate on the second example, with:

```
parbe1 = {T1 -> 50, P -> 5, q -> 1/10};
parbe2 = {P -> 3, q -> 1/10};
```

I use your other definitions throughout, except for `ticks`, which I redefine as the following list:

```
ClearAll[ticks]
ticks =
  {#, NumberForm[Rescale[#, {0, 1}, minmax], {20, 18}]} & /@
    FindDivisions[{0, 1}, 8];
```

In the following, I rescale your dependent variable data manually before feeding it `ListLinePlot`, with no loss of precision, then calculate appropriate vertical ticks as shown above:

```
ListLinePlot[
  (*this does the manual rescaling: *)
  Transpose@{xlog, Rescale[Tcvalues]}, 

  (* notice the {0, 1} vertical scale, since data has been rescaled above *)
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 1}},  

  (* the formatting options below are from your original code: *)
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.015],
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 0.8, ImageSize -> 400,
  FrameStyle -> Black, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 13,
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(10\)]\) (be)", 
                 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(C\)]\)"}, 
  RotateLabel -> False,
  FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {Automatic, None}},
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]
]
```

[image: plot with manually rescaled data and manually generated ticks]

---

Having done all this, this plot is still not very legible. An alternative would be to use the vertical axis to represent the *difference* between the overall minimum and each value, rather than the values themselves.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.